# how to Implement jQuery Validation rule for multiselect box?

Tags: javascript, jquery-validate, multi-select

Here is my html select box (options will come by ajax call) with multiselect function and validation

```
<select id="chapterId" name="chapter[]" class="multiselect-ui form-control" multiple="multiple"></select>

$('#chapterId').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true
    });

var $validator = $("#orderPaper").validate({
            rules: {
                 'chapter[]': {required: true, min: 1},
            },
            messages: {
                'chapter[]': {required: "Please select chapter"},
            }
});
```

also multiselect.js is included properly.
its shows error every time 'Please select chapter' weather chapters selected or not.
I also checked that chapters are selected properly i can also get selected chapter ids.
but the jquery error is showing every time.

Comment: did you try chapter instead of chapter[] in your jquery validator definition

Comment: Yes, @fxlacroix but after that it does not validate the chapter field.

Comment: maybe you can check the validate() demo page for jquery, but as i see they use attribute directly in the tag input... 2 cents ;)
https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/radio-checkbox-select-demo.html

Comment: So it looks like you're using a plugin to change the appearance of the multi-select element.  If that's the case, then the original `select` is hidden and will not be validated.  You're going to have to take the time to construct a better, more complete demo, including enough HTML to reproduce the issue.  Please fix the code in your question and include a jsFiddle demo.

Comment: After some testing i found that it has issue with ajax loaded options only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use custom validation rule. Try with this.

```
var $validator = $("#orderPaper").validate({
    rules: {
        'chapter[]': {required: true, needsSelection: true},
    },
    messages: {
        'chapter[]': {required: "Please select chapter", needsSelection: "Please select chapter"},
    }
});
$.validator.addMethod("needsSelection", function (value, element) {
    var count = $(element).find('option:selected').length;
    return count > 0;
});
```

Comment: Oh yes, thanks @Virendra Jadeja. it's working for me :).